# Are data properties dangerous?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

Use the following simple example:

```
var MyObject = {
    name: '',
    object_id: '',
    awesomeFunction: function() { console.log('awesome'); }
};
```

Now, this is fine until I think about prototypal inheritance.  Say i now want to inherit from this object:

```
 var child_object = Object.create(MyObject);
```

This instantly causes problems because the child object has not specified the `name` and `object_id` properties which will therefore be taken from the parent object (prototype). And there is no native way to enforce that child objects are created with their own versions of these, right?

Is this understanding correct?

If so, am i thinking about inheritance in javascript incorrectly?

Should objects be treated as containers for functions instead?

Comment: Assignment goes to the new object. But until then, changes in `MyObject` will be visible through `child_object`.

Comment: Yes exactly my point.  Thats ripe for bugs, isnt it?

Comment: You said `prototypal inheritance` in your question, but I don't see any prototypes :)

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @thefourtheye - isnt Object.create doing this?

Comment: Do you want to clone or inherit this object (not sure if inheriting an object makes sense) ? I don't think you chose a good example for your question, because strings are immutable.

Comment: @Johan - simply trying to learn javascript but keep gettin stuck when it comes to objects and inheritance. in the example above im trying to illustrate that there is no way to force objects that inherit from others to always ensure that certain properties are created on the child objcet.  Otherwise its very likely bugs can happen.  im trying to determine if this is true, or im misunderstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And there is no native way to enforce that child objects are created with their own versions of these, right?

If you want all the instances to have those attributes, by default, then you should not inherit but construct them. The normal way to do this would be

```
function Parent(name, id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id   = id;
}

function Child(name, id) {
     Parent.call(this, name, id);
}
```

Now, when you create an instance of `Child`, they will have their own version of `name` and `id`. Also, you can assign values to them while creating them itself.